# betababel: You haven't defined the language polutonikogreek yet

Tags: errors, babel, greek, betababel

For many years I used the package `betababel` to combine Latin and Greek letters in one document, but since version `2014.20141024-1` of `texlive-lang-greek`, the simple example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}

\begin{document}
\bcode{lo/gos}
\end{document}
```

(which worked with the previous version) produces this error when compiling with `pdflatex`:

> ```
> Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language polutonikogreek yet.
> ```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice question and thanks for the MWE. Maybe, you send a notice to the maintainer of `betababel`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know if this runs into some clashes, but as `betababel` loads `babel` as well, it should be safe to do:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}

\begin{document}
    \bcode{lo/gos}
\end{document}
```

As written in your output, the `babel` option `polutonikogreek` was missing. As `betababel` does not offer this option, just load it via the original `babel`.

[image]

Comment: The manual for `betababel` says explicitly *not* to do this.

Comment: @cfr I fear the `betababel` documentation is outdated: `betababel` was last updated 2005, while `babel-greek` and  the `babel` kernel were last updated 2016.

Comment: @wicho The problem is that `betababel` wants to load Babel with options. If you load Babel first, that isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

The packages `betababel` does not seem to have received updates in the last decade(s). I strongly discourage the use of it. (I could not get it up and running on a TexLive 2021 installation.)

I recommend to directly write Greek in your Tex file. Use Greek stickers on your keyboard and select a Greek layout in your operating system.

An example would look like

```
\documentclass{article}

% Set the font (output) encodings
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is no longer required (since 2018)

% Greek-specific commands
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
\textgreek{Αυτή είναι μια σύντομη περιγραφή του θέματος}
\end{abstract}

Latin text can also be added to the document.
\end{document}
```

adapted from [Overleaf Greek introduction](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Greek#Language-specific_packages_and_commands)