# Setting up psgreek fonts for betababel

Tags: fonts, greek, betababel

I'm using TeX Live (Debian) with `betababel` to insert ancient greek text. Since I'm required to use a sans-serif font, I wanted to change the greek font with the `psgreek` package to find one that fits Helvetica.

For some reason, choosing a font from `psgreek` has no effect at all.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[greek]{betababel}
\usepackage[
regular
%garamond
%oxonia
%oldface
%milan
%kerkis
%cmr
%cmss
%cmtt
]{psgreek}

\begin{document}
Test.
\begin{betacode}
*e)ge/neto de! e)n tai=s h(me/rais e)kei/nais e)ch=lqen 

do/gma para! *kai/saros *au)gou/stou 

a)pogra/fesqai pa=san th!n oi)koume/nhn.
\end{betacode}
\end{document}
```

Everythings seems to be installed correctly, no error message is shown. The document compiles without any problem, except it always shows the default greek font, whatever option from `psgreek` I coose.
Whether `latex` or `pdflatex` is used, makes no difference.

Anyone got an idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Loading `betababel` after `babel` is probably problematic as it wants to pass options to `babel`. You might want to note that `psgreek` is available at http://ctan.org/pkg/psgreek since it is not part of standard TeX distributions. Is there any particular reason you want to use this rather than, say, one of the GFS fonts? (Anyway, CTAN is worth a look right now!)

Comment: Any particular reason to prefer beta code over other latin transliteration schemes?

Comment: I never really bothered using others than the default font, because I quite like it, so I've never come across the GFS fonts. But I'll have a look, if `psgreek` won't work at all …  Beta code is just the first one I came in contact with. ;-) Writing directly in greek would be fine, but I'm working at university most times and need a method that doesn't require greek keyboard or utf8 support.

Comment: @Julian Why the UTF8 restriction in a university environment? Sounds odd... Any possibility of using XeTeX?

Comment: @Dɑvïd The restriction, IIUC, is that not all the computers in the Lab may have access to a polytonic Greek input method.

Comment: @wicho - That's what I wondered. If OP's sample text is anything to go by, then copy/paste from [authoritative online sources](http://www.bibelwissenschaft.de/online-bibeln/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/lesen-im-bibeltext/bibel/text/lesen/stelle/52/20001/29999/ch/d27e7647c57da0426cb4f0728d9d4dca/) is a very simple matter. FWIW.

Comment: @Dɑvïd Users can't install anything or change settings on the computers, so I'm not able to change the keyboard. If I could, I'm not sure if typing greek with Window's own encoding would cause trouble when I edit the file on linux.  Anyway, copy/paste is of course nice, but the text was just an example …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is only to typeset your text with a sans font, and you don't mind the CM family, you may try this preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{betababel}
\let\rmdefault\sfdefault
```

The trick is in the last line.

Both `betababel` and `psgreek` are rather old (2005 and 2007, respectively), and the `babel/greek` interface has changed in the meanwhile, so they need a major overhaul. Please file a bug report to the corresponding maintainers.

As a workaround, you may try to add the `textalpha` (for LGR encoding) and `substitutefont` packages and say, v.gr.

```
\substitutefont{LGR}{\sfdefault}{hml}
```

to setup the `milan` Greek font, which is the only "sans" font in the `psgreek` bundle, afaik.

```
\usepackage{textalpha,substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\sfdefault}{hml}
\begin{document}
With the LGR encoding:

\ensuregreek{>en >arq'h <=hn <o l'ogoc}

And with Beta Code:

\begin{betacode}
*e)ge/neto de! e)n tai=s h(me/rais e)kei/nais e)ch=lqen 

do/gma para! *kai/saros *au)gou/stou 

a)pogra/fesqai pa=san th!n oi)koume/nhn.
\end{betacode}
\end{document}
```

You may need to fix a small bug in `betababel.sty`, line 386: it says

```
      $ifnum$suffix@=58$@ddToText{s}%
```

it should say

```
      $ifnum$suffix@=58$@ddToText{c}%
```

Output:

[image: BetaBabelMilan]

Comment: Wow, using `\let\rmdefault\sfdefault` with Helvetica really did the trick! Thanks! @cfr I think, I'll go without `psgreek` and use the GFS fonts instead.  Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

May I gently point out that package authors spend a great deal of time and effort to document their packages so that users can use them effectively? When something does not work, therefore, it is almost always a good idea to start by looking at the manuals of the packages you are using.

For the record, I'd never heard of `betababel` or `psgreek` before. So if I can identify a problem in your example code in 2 minutes by opening the documentation, you probably could have done the same thing in a fraction of the time it took to write the question.

Also for the record, yours is a far, far, far better question than many, especially most first questions. So this is really by way of expressing a general gripe.

`betababel`'s manual notes the following on page 3:

> Since `betababel` internally loads the babel package by itself, there
>   must *not* be a `\usepackage[...]{babel}` command in your document
>   preamble.

The manual totals a whopping 7 pages, including the abstract and contents on page 1 and the change log on the last 1.5 pages. So it is hardly in that class of manuals so overwhelming you need another manual to help you find your way through the first one.

## EDIT

If you load the options for Babel as class options, `betababel` can still load `babel` as it wants. Alternatively, you can pass the options for `babel` as options when loading `betababel`.

I don't have `psgreek`. However, the Greek Font Society offers several options, some of which support Latin script as well as Greek.

For example,

```
\documentclass[polutonikogreek, british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
\usepackage[greek]{betababel}

\begin{document}
Test.
\begin{betacode}
*e)ge/neto de! e)n tai=s h(me/rais e)kei/nais e)ch=lqen

do/gma para! *kai/saros *au)gou/stou

a)pogra/fesqai pa=san th!n oi)koume/nhn.
\end{betacode}
\end{document}
```

[image: GFS NeoHellenic]

Comment: Sorry, I know what you mean … Actually, loading the `babel` package in addition is a workaround for another problem (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224004/betababel-you-havent-defined-the-language-polutonikogreek-yet)) and worked just fine. I now defined the language to be used as a `\documentclass` option, like suggested by `babel`'s manual: `\documentclass[a4paper, polutonikogreek]{article}` But the original problem of `psgreek` doing nothing remains.

Comment: You can pass the options to `betababel` as shown in the manual. But passing them as class options is generally recommended for Babel anyway. How did you install `psgreek`? Are the fonts installed correctly?

Comment: @Julian Please see edit above for an example with a GFS font. I don't have the `psgreek` package installed. But if you need it in particular, please explain how you installed it.

Comment: That double call to `polutonikogreek` and `greek` doesn't make much sense; that's why I fear the `betababel` UI is messed up.

Comment: @wicho Yes, I think you may be right about that. In fact, `betababel` is passing `greek` to `babel` anyway. Do you know what Babel does if both `greek` and `polutonikogreek` are passed? (I'm assuming here that the OP has `teubner.sty`. If not, it passes `polutonikogreek` instead.) I guess the question is why the OP wants to pass `polutonikogreek` to Babel here. Maybe. (I don't know anything about typesetting Greek, so maybe this is obvious.)

Comment: I know that `betababel`passes `polutonikogreek` as default, or it should. In fact, if I don't pass the option  to `babel` or the document class 'by hand' I get this: `Error: You haven't defined the language polutonikogreek yet.`

Comment: @Julian Did you remove the generated files before recompiling? A stale `.aux` file will cause that error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this does not directly answer the question, and involves using Unicode, which apparently is not possible ... but XeLaTeX would be so much easier, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}

\newfontfamily{\Gksf}{Gentium Plus}
\newfontfamily{\Gksa}{Fira Sans}

\begin{document}

Serif (Gentium Plus):\\
{\Gksf Ἐγένετο δὲ ἐν ταῖς ἡμέραις ἐκείναις ἐξῆλθεν δόγμα παρὰ Καίσαρος Αὐγούστου ἀπογράφεσθαι πᾶσαν τὴν οἰκουμένην.}

Sans (Fira Sans):\\
{\Gksa Ἐγένετο δὲ ἐν ταῖς ἡμέραις ἐκείναις ἐξῆλθεν δόγμα παρὰ Καίσαρος Αὐγούστου ἀπογράφεσθαι πᾶσαν τὴν οἰκουμένην.}

\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image: Greek screenshot]

Posted just in case OP's restrictions might be relaxed.